# Cannot add any shared projects to solution in VS2019

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, intellisense, visual-studio-2019

I am using VS2019 16.0.0 Preview 4.4

If I create a new C# WPF project, then right click on the solution and click "Add new project". Create a C# class project and add it.

Now if I right click on references on the main startup project and click "add reference". Under shared projects the list is empty and I cannot add anything.

If I open an existing project with shared projects that was created in VS2017, all references to the shared project show up as intellisense errors with red squiggles. If I run the solution it compiles and runs fine.

It seems the GUI component cannot see any referenced projects, however at the MSBUILD level everything works correctly.

I have tried deleting the .VS folder with no luck.

Why do shared projects not work in VS2019 ?

Jere is a screenshot of a VS2017 project which opens, compiles and runs fine, but all the shared project references show up as red intellisense errors.

I have raised a question on the developer community forums with no response for over a week
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/490528/shared-projects-is-empty-and-all-referenced-projec.html

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, do you mean the program compiles and runs fine with so many CS0234 errors in vs2019? The rebuild succeed in VS2019? I've tried using shared project in a solution, and open it with vs2019. All works fine. (Same vs version)

Comment: If you create a simple app which uses shared project in VS2017, and open it with VS2019, same issue persist? If it persists, could you share the simple sample here by one-drive so that I can check it directly for you:)

Comment: Correct, clean and rebuild mean the program builds and runs fine despite 100% of references being reported as missing/not existing via intellisense. If i create a new solution in 2017 and open in 2019 the problem persists. I will try and make a repo and upload it otherwise if you contact me privately Im happy to do screensharing/remote session if that helps. I really want to use 2019 but this is a roadblock.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Ok it seems the intellisense bug is only a problem on our large company project, I cant reproduce it otherwise. I can upload the csproj file privately if that helps.

Comment: >> If I remove the shared project in 2017, then try and add it back in 2019 the projects list is empty and it cannot see any of the shared projects. For this, could you please share a similar sample by github or one-drive, cause it works well on my side in same vs2019 version.It would be difficult for us to trouble shooting if we can't reproduce the issue.

Comment: Everything seems to have magically resolved itself since the other day with no changes. I can't recreate the problem anymore.

Comment: AHH, good news.

Answer (score 1):

> Under shared projects the list is empty and I cannot add anything.

As I know, we can't **share the projects (shared) across solution.**

Which means if we create a new project, choose "add reference", under shared projects the list would be empty unless we create a new shared project in the solution or add an existing shared project to this solution.

> If I open an existing project with shared projects that was created in
>   VS2017, all references to the shared project show up as intellisense
>   errors with red squiggles. If I run the solution it compiles and runs
>   fine.

Open the vs2017 project in vs2019, choose "rebuild", the same issue persists? If so, 
remove the shared project in the solution, right-click solution=>add existing project to add it back. After that, re-add the reference to the sharedproject.

Actually, the shared project works well on my side with similar vs version. And for more info about why shared project can't run across solution see [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/abe19e11-5f4c-4d1d-a18c-31982ae910bf/shared-project-between-solutions?forum=visualstudiogeneral).

Comment: VS2017 works fine always. No matter what I try (rebuilding, cleaning, deleting .vs) 2019 will not work. If I remove the shared project in 2017, then try and add it back in 2019 the projects list is empty and it cannot see any of the shared projects so I have to add it back using 2017

Comment: You're choosing the wrong item. There is a C++ Shared Project and a C# Shared project. Choose the latter